# Remove duplicates from a list of objects based on property in Java 8

Tags: java, list, java-8

I am trying to remove duplicates from a List of objects based on some property.

can we do it in a simple way using java 8

```
List<Employee> employee
```

Can we remove duplicates from it based on `id` property of employee. I have seen posts removing duplicate strings form arraylist of string.

Comment: Why you use List for that...use Set instead of List.

Comment: do you want to search for duplicates of employee.name? or what is your purpose, please give more information

Comment: @Ranjeet that only works if `Employee` properly implements `equals` and `hashCode` in such a way as to correctly identify duplicates.

Comment: great answer https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/java-stream-distinct-examples/

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You can get a stream from the `List` and put in in the `TreeSet` from which you provide a custom comparator that compares id uniquely.

Then if you really need a list you can put then back this collection into an ArrayList.

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection;

...
List<Employee> unique = employee.stream()
                                .collect(collectingAndThen(toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(comparingInt(Employee::getId))),
                                                           ArrayList::new));
```

Given the example:

```
List<Employee> employee = Arrays.asList(new Employee(1, "John"), new Employee(1, "Bob"), new Employee(2, "Alice"));
```

It will output:

```
[Employee{id=1, name='John'}, Employee{id=2, name='Alice'}]
```

---

Another idea could be to use a wrapper that wraps an employee and have the equals and hashcode method based with its id:

```
class WrapperEmployee {
    private Employee e;

    public WrapperEmployee(Employee e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

    public Employee unwrap() {
        return this.e;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        WrapperEmployee that = (WrapperEmployee) o;
        return Objects.equals(e.getId(), that.e.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(e.getId());
    }
}
```

Then you wrap each instance, call `distinct()`, unwrap them and collect the result in a list.

```
List<Employee> unique = employee.stream()
                                .map(WrapperEmployee::new)
                                .distinct()
                                .map(WrapperEmployee::unwrap)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

In fact, I think you can make this wrapper generic by providing a function that will do the comparison:

```
public class Wrapper<T, U> {
    private T t;
    private Function<T, U> equalityFunction;

    public Wrapper(T t, Function<T, U> equalityFunction) {
        this.t = t;
        this.equalityFunction = equalityFunction;
    }

    public T unwrap() {
        return this.t;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Wrapper<T, U> that = (Wrapper<T, U>) o;
        return Objects.equals(equalityFunction.apply(this.t), that.equalityFunction.apply(that.t));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(equalityFunction.apply(this.t));
    }
}
```

and the mapping will be:

```
.map(e -> new Wrapper<>(e, Employee::getId))
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is a far better answer than the wrapper one :). Wrapper is obvious, but the first one is much better. I wasnt aware of collectingAndThen

Comment: I implemented this way but some time I get null pointer exception when executing the test cases. Strange thing is that, when I re execute the test cases, the error goes away. Do you have any idea why this happens. It would be great if you can help me on this.

Comment: @Patan Hard to tell without the test cases, check if you don't have any null reference in the list.

Comment: The first example works for me but I don't understand why :)

Comment: @Bevor It uses the set constructor that takes a comparator as parameter. In the example, every employe with the same id will be considered equals and will be unique in the resulting set.

Comment: for older Java? On Android many of these works only from API 24

Comment: Made it for Android API 14: `TreeSet<Video> videos = new TreeSet<>((o1, o2) -> o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId()));
videos.addAll(<YOU_LIST>);
return new ArrayList<>(videos);`

Comment: `collectingAndThen` - interesting thing which will allow to write such algorithm just in one line. Though I'm not sure if it's really that great - we get quite long line why just don't write two or more lines?

Comment: This solution is `O(NlogN)` just to remove duplicates, because it uses `TreeSet` (and `TreeSet.add` operation is `O(logN)`).

Comment: This example is weird, IntelliJ IDEA won't suggest to add imports automatically. Seems it's not a good idea to use `import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.collectingAndThen;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection;
`

Comment: In your first answer, instead of using `collectingAndThen`, would it be more efficient to just wrap the solution using the `new ArrayList<(ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` constructor? So the final code would be `List<Employee> unique = new ArrayList<>(employee.stream().collect(toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(comparingInt(Employee::getId)))));`

Comment: @cbender I want to use `List<Employee> unique = employee.stream()
                                .collect(collectingAndThen(toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(comparingInt(Employee::getId))),
                                                           ArrayList::new));` 
But with two fields. Here only one field given, `getId`. How can I check two fields to remove duplicate.

Comment: @AvijitBarua you can compare as many fields as you want. The `TreeSet` constructor will accept any `Comparator`. In Java 8 and onward the `comparingInt` method is just a quick way to create a Comparator that compares `int` fields. If you want to add another field to the comparison you can use the `thenComparing` chained to the original compare so it would look something like `comparingInt(Employee::getId).thenComparing(Employee::getName)`. This seems like a good article explaining Comparators - https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing.

Comment: How to get the last updated value like new Employee(1, "Bob")?

Answer (score 105):

The easiest way to do it directly in the list is

```
HashSet<Object> seen = new HashSet<>();
employee.removeIf(e -> !seen.add(e.getID()));
```

- `removeIf` will remove an element if it meets the specified criteria
- `Set.add` will return `false` if it did not modify the `Set`, i.e. already contains the value
- combining these two, it will remove all elements (employees) whose id has been encountered before

Of course, it only works if the list supports removal of elements.

Comment: You assume that id is unique, what if I have composite key

Comment: @user3871754: you need an object holding the composite key and having appropriate `equals` and `hashCode` implementations, e.g. `yourList.removeIf(e -> !seen.add(Arrays.asList(e.getFirstKeyPart(), e.getSecondKeyPart()));`. Composing the key via `Arrays.asList` works with an arbitrary number of components, whereas for small numbers of components a dedicated key type might be more efficient.

Comment: what do you mean all? I need to left at least one

Answer (score 66):

If you can make use of `equals`, then filter the list by using `distinct` within a stream (see answers above). If you can not or don't want to override the `equals` method, you can  `filter` the stream in the following way for any property, e.g. for the property Name (the same for the property Id etc.):

```
Set<String> nameSet = new HashSet<>();
List<Employee> employeesDistinctByName = employees.stream()
            .filter(e -> nameSet.add(e.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This was pretty fine, it takes advantage of the simple functionality of filter that decide to filter or maintain every element based on a predicate (predicate to apply to each element to determine if it should be included), based on the property (String type) insertion in a set : true if newly inserted, false if it exists already...that was smart ! work great for me !

Comment: This example is good and simple.

Comment: Does it work fine in multi-threaded scenarios / parallel streams? I mean, is it thread safe kinda thing?

Comment: This is nice solution to remove duplicate items from the list. But my question was to get item form 2 list whose ids are not same.

Comment: wow! nice and simple.

Answer (score 23):

Another solution is to use a Predicate, then you can use this in any filter:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctBy(Function<? super T, ?> f) {
  Set<Object> objects = new ConcurrentHashSet<>();
  return t -> objects.add(f.apply(t));
}
```

**Then simply reuse the predicate anywhere:**

```
employees.stream().filter(distinctBy(e -> e.getId));
```

Note: in the JavaDoc of filter, which says it takes a stateless Predicte. Actually, this works fine even if the stream is parallel.

**About other solutions:**

1) Using `.collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(..)).values()` is a good solution, but it's annoying if you want to sort and keep the order.

2) `stream.removeIf(e->!seen.add(e.getID()));` is also another very good solution. But we need to make sure the collection implemented removeIf, for example it will throw exception if we construct the collection use `Arrays.asList(..)`.

Comment: Great solution when you can't override equals method and don't want to bloat your lambda with Set/List conversions like the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why this is not added in the java 8 library. Using it something like `stream().distinctBy(Employee::Id)` would be of great convenience

Comment: f maybe null and throw nullpointer.

Comment: Nice! You could change `new ConcurrentHashSet` to `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` if you dont have a ConcurrentHashSet

Comment: Amazing solution, really sad it hasn't found its way into the JDK yet.

Answer (score 18):

Try this code:

```
Collection<Employee> nonDuplicatedEmployees = employees.stream()
   .<Map<Integer, Employee>> collect(HashMap::new,(m,e)->m.put(e.getId(), e), Map::putAll)
   .values();
```

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me:

```
list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You need to implement equals, of course

Comment: You need to implement equals, of course

Comment: @Andronicus I added my comment into my response.

Comment: hashcode() also should be overridden, 
but according to the distinct() method of the Stream API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--
only equals should be

Answer (score 11):

If order does not matter and when it's more performant to run in parallel, Collect to a Map and then get values:

```
employee.stream().collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(Employee::getId, Function.identity(), (p, q) -> p)).values()
```

Comment: So, I guess something like this if you want a list back: `employee.stream().collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(Employee::getId, Function.identity(), (p, q) -> p)).values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList())`. And, regarding parallel, you can you use it or not here - I mean parallelStream API?

Comment: @RokT.. no need to re-create a stream, just wrap it in an ArrayList. 
ex:- new ArrayList<>(.stream().collect()......values());

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of good answers here but I didn't find the one about using `reduce` method. So for your case, you can apply it in following way:

```java
 List<Employee> employeeList = employees.stream()
      .reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (List<Employee> accumulator, Employee employee) ->
      {
        if (accumulator.stream().noneMatch(emp -> emp.getId().equals(employee.getId())))
        {
          accumulator.add(employee);
        }
        return accumulator;
      }, (acc1, acc2) ->
      {
        acc1.addAll(acc2);
        return acc1;
      });
```

Comment: working with parallel Streams there's a chance that the combiner will add together employees with the same id again.. in that case you need to check there aswell for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Another version which is simple

```
BiFunction<TreeSet<Employee>,List<Employee> ,TreeSet<Employee>> appendTree = (y,x) -> (y.addAll(x))? y:y;

TreeSet<Employee> outputList = appendTree.apply(new TreeSet<Employee>(Comparator.comparing(p->p.getId())),personList);
```

Comment: This is an obfuscated version of `TreeSet<Employee> outputList = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(p->p.getId())); outputList.addAll(personList);` The straight-forward code is much simpler.