# Display duplicate attribute values once in Java object list

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have a list of java objects as below

[image]

I want to convert it to a list with 'Camera flash faulty' and 'Camera Housing Damaged' only once for the first object, like the one below.

[image]

Is there something that can be done with the solution mentioned here ?
[Remove duplicates from a list of objects based on property in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670116/remove-duplicates-from-a-list-of-objects-based-on-property-in-java-8/39717788#39717788)

Comment: Collection with unique values suggests that you're looking for a set: `new HashSet<>(list)`

Comment: Why do you want to *clear* the first attribute ? Does it bother you ? Which problem lies behind that ? It looks like a good candidate for a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Do you really think, it’s a good idea to modify objects in that way depending on the position in one list? What, if these objects are also contained in a different list, in a different order? What if you remove the first object from the list?

Comment: This is for the display purpose, the requirement is to display attribute values only once. I am fetching these objects from database, ordering by first column, then second column. so all will be grouped together

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the properties to a `Set` (Sets don't allow duplicates), if the value is already in the set, the method `add` returns false, so you can set to empty the property in the object:

```
Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();
for (MyObject obj : myList) {
    if (!values.add(obj.getValue())) {
        obj.setValue("");
    }
}
```

Another alternative is to group all object with the same attribute value, then skip the first element of each group and set the attribute value to empty for all other objects in the group:

```
    myList.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getValue))
      .forEach((k, v) -> v.stream().skip(1).forEach(o->o.setValue("")));
```

Comment: David, your second solution is getting me the list with first column in desired manner, but surprisingly its throwing java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist when trying to use that list even though there is no database fetch further. I am processing the list after fetch.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking an example of `Employee` which have some duplicate id's.

Lets say you have a list as

```
List<Employee> employee
```

Add them into `HashSet`, which does not allow duplicates.

```
HashSet<Object> seen=new HashSet<>();
employee.removeIf(e->!seen.add(e.getID()));
```

Comment: FallAndLearn
1,890●1●3●15
     
I don't want to remove objects with same attribute values, I want to keep them, but make attribute value empty, like in the second list I posted. It doesn't mean those objects are duplicate, it has more attributes which may have different values