# Remove duplicate from List java8

Tags: java-8

I have a class below, and wanted to remove duplicate person which contain same name, how to do by using Java8 Lambda, expected List contains p1, p3 from the below.

### Person:

```
public class Person {

public int id;
public String name;
public String city;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

}
```

### Testing:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Testing {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.setId(1);
    p1.setName("Venkat");
    p1.setCity("Bangalore");
    Person p2 = new Person();

    p2.setId(2);
    p2.setName("Venkat");
    p2.setCity("Bangalore");

    Person p3 = new Person();
    p3.setId(3);
    p3.setName("Kumar");
    p3.setCity("Chennai");

    persons.add(p1);
    persons.add(p2);
    persons.add(p3);

}
}
```

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670116/remove-duplicates-from-a-list-of-objects-based-on-property-in-java-8

Comment: override equals & hashcode methods  in   Person class  for duplication removal using Set

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property)

Answer (score 35):

You could filter them out and generate a unique `Set`:

```
Set<Person> set = persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> 
                 new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName))));
```

Or even nicer:

```
Set<String> namesAlreadySeen = new HashSet<>();

persons.removeIf(p -> !namesAlreadySeen.add(p.getName()));
```

Comment: ooh, you faster than me, +1! you should tell the OP to make the `persons` to `List<Person>`  rather than `List<Object>`.

Comment: You actually don't need a stream for this, do you? Just create the `TreeSet` with the comparator and then use `addAll`.

Comment: No need for block syntax here, you can use the compact expression syntax just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672489/2711488).

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner you're right, I don't have to use streams... thx

Comment: Helped me with some other kind of problem :p

Answer (score 35):

```
List<Person> personsWithoutDuplicates = persons.stream()
 .distinct()
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You sure that's going to work if the class does override equals and hash?

Comment: @RobertMoskal: the question is, rather, why you'd want to sneak around implementing `equals` and `hashCode` in the first place.

Comment: distinct - Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to Object.equals(Object)) of this stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Person> modified = pesrons.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(()->new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName)))).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will return a list of non duplicates based on Name.

You can refer this also [Remove duplicates from a list of objects based on property in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670116/remove-duplicates-from-a-list-of-objects-based-on-property-in-java-8)