# Remove Objects with a duplicate ID from a list?

Tags: java, list, duplicates

How can I remove all objects in a list that have the same ID?

For example in the following list:

```
    Person person1 = new Person();
    person1.setId("1");

    Person person2 = new Person();
    person2.setId("1"); //ie same as Person1

    Person person3 = new Person();
    person3.setId("2");

    List<Person> PersonList = new ArrayList<>();
    PersonList.add(person1);
    PersonList.add(person2);
    PersonList.add(person3);
```

My Method below works for the above but not when there are multiple duplicates, how can I solve this case also?

```
public List<Person> removeDuplicatesFromList(List<Person> personList){

        for (int i = 0; i < personList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < personList.size(); j++) {

                if(personList.get(i).getId().equalsIgnoreCase(personList.get(j).getId())){

                    personList.remove(personList.get(j));
                }else{

                }
            }
        }

        return personList;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property)

Comment: Why not using a HashSet ? Override "equals" on Person to make a comparaison based on Id. Then you would'nt have duplicates.

Comment: @olikaf Why override equals (probably a very bad idea) if you can just use a `Map<ID, Person>`?

Comment: You sohuld not remove elements from a list while you are iterating over it!

Comment: Use a set and it will automatically do it or use Lambda Expressionsµ

Comment: @LuaiGhunim please explain via example

Comment: @java123999 Java8 introdcued new concepts of stream and lambda expression,derived from haskell. Check this example `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418738/remove-duplicate-from-list-java8` Here people have explained , how to removed duplicates without loop and that is also beautiful

Comment: @tobias_k  you can override equals if it make sense to compare Person by IDs. Same IDs, then they are equals. But in fact HashSet use hashCode() :-). But then again, same IDs should implies same hash code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @tobias_k already commented, I suggest you to use [`Map<String, Person>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead of `List<Person>`.
This will avoid duplicates in the first place, so that there is no need to remove them.

Your modified code would like this:

```
Person person1 = new Person();
person1.setId("1");

Person person2 = new Person();
person2.setId("1"); //i.e. same as person1

Person person3 = new Person();
person3.setId("2");

Map<String, Person> personMap = new HashMap<>();
personMap.put(person1.getId(), person1);
personMap.put(person2.getId(), person2);
personMap.put(person3.getId(), person3);
```

Calling `personMap.get("1")` then would give `person2`,
and `personMap.get("2")` would give `person3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Map. Use key as person id and person object as value

```
public List<Person> removeDuplicatesFromList(List<Person> personList){
   Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<String, Person>();
   List<Person> newPersonList = new ArrayList<>();
   for(Person p:personList){
       map.put(p.getId(),p);
   }
   Iterator itr=map.keySet().iterator();
   while (itr.hasNext()) {
     String id =  itr.next().toString();
     newPersonList.add((Person)map.get(id));
    }
  return newPersonList;
 }
```