# Java HashSet does not call overriden equals but it should

Tags: java, set, addition, equals, hashset

In main method I create two different equal objects.

```
private static Set<Cards> allCombs = new HashSet<>();

cards = new Cards();
cards.add(new Card(1, 10));
cards.add(new Card(1, 12));

Cards cards2 = new Cards();
cards2.add(new Card(1, 10));
cards2.add(new Card(1, 12));

System.out.println(cards.toString() + " " + cards2.toString() + " " + (cards == cards2) + " " + cards.equals(cards2));

allCombs.add(cards);
allCombs.add(cards2);

System.out.println(allCombs);
```

My expectations is that set `allCombs` has one element because two objects of Cards are equal. I checked it and DEBUG is from `equals` method and objects are equal (comparison from `println`). But they are not same reference...

Why `add` method from `HashSet` does not call `Cards`'s equals method while adding element?

```
DEBUG 6_QT 6_QT true
6_QT 6_QT false true
[6_QT, 6_QT]
```

Comment: Did you override `hashCode` in `Card` as well?

Comment: I've seen that you also have a class `Cards`, so you'd need to override `hashCode` there as well

Comment: Why I need hashCode in Cards? I  thought that hashCode from super class (Object) will be equal and then Set's add method compares by equals

Comment: You're using a `HashSet`, and as the name suggests uses the `hashCode` to determine equalness. Also, you should always override both `equals` and `hashCode` to keep the contract consistent

Comment: _I thought that hashCode from super class (Object) will be equal_ Why did you think this?

Comment: @TomaszEkner - The [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) for `Object::equals` and `Object::hashCode` explain the relationship that is required between these two methods.  When you override either of these methods, that relationship (aka the hashcode <-> equals contract) must be maintained ... or else your hash tables will behave incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

From a purely equivalence perspective, your Card class should look something like this.  It's most important to use `@Override` to ensure your overridden method signatures are correct.

```
class Card {
       int suit;
       int rank;
       public Card (int suit, int rank) {
          this.suit = suit;
          this.rank = rank;
       }
       @Override
       public int hashCode() {
           return Objects.hash(suit, rank);
       }
       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object obj) {
           if (obj == this) {
                return true;
           }
           if (obj == null) {
              return false;
           }
           if (obj instanceof Card) {
                Card arg = (Card) obj;
                if (arg.suit == suit && arg.rank == rank) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
       }
       // other methods here
}
```

Comment: Correct. But I bet `suit` and `rank` are reference type `Integer`

Answer (score 1):

The Hashset use hashCode method to compare two objects.
You must override this method in your object: Cards.

Comment: This is a rather bad implementation of `hashCode`. Honestly, please just let your IDE generate it...

Comment: You can use `Objects.hashCode(Object... params)` to generate a consistent hashCode for all your fields. No need for manual calculation

Comment: *"It's just an example."* - Bad examples are not good.  People copy them.

Comment: @QBrute  For multiple arguments it's `Objects.hash(Object... params);`

Comment: @WJS Yes you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You have contract violation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods based on the behavior you describe. If you have overridden `equals()` in your class you need to properly override `hashCode()` as well.

Method [HashSet#add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add-E-) uses an internal map and first calculates `hashcode` of your object and invoke `equals()` ONLY if a basket with the calculated hashcode is present in this internal map. This basket is obviously absent in your case so no need invoke your `equals()` at all here.

1. **`hashCode()` must be overrided in every class that overrides `equals()`**. Otherwise you'll not be able to properly use instances of your class in any data structures based on hash tables, including `HashSet`. Read [what Joshua Bloch writes about it in Effective Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46766898/1177031)
2. **`hashCode()` must produce the same integer result** on each of 2 objects are equal according to `equals()`.
   Read [javadoc of Object class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) to fully understand the contract between `equals()` and `hashCode()`
3. See [source code of HashSet class](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java) to understand how `HashSet` and `HashMap` work and why your `equals()` method is not used in your given code.
4. Remember to use annotation `@Override` to make sure you really override the default method and avoid hidden mistakes in the method signature.

And show the implementation of your classes `Card` and `Cards` to define what's wrong exactly from the points above.