# Java 8: Compare elements in Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, stream, java-stream

i have an `ArrayList` of *students*: 
 
How can i efficiently compare all elements in the list to make sure no two elements have the same `ssn` or `lName` value?

```
ArrayList<Student> students = getStudents();

public class Student { 
    private String id;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String ssn;
}
```

Comment: These are two separate questions, compare elements and make sure no duplicate ssn. Do you want a method like `containsDuplicateSSN`?

Comment: actually, just need to ensure that there are no duplicate ssn, lName values

Comment: Are students store in database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from a list of objects based on property in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670116/remove-duplicates-from-a-list-of-objects-based-on-property-in-java-8)

Comment: @ShanuGupta no, the arrayList is user input

Comment: @ShanuGupta my function is called at the time the input is taken!

Comment: If you don't want duplicated value, simply use a `Set`, that will be easier. `new HashSet(list)`, note that this required `equals` and `hashcode` to be implemented correctly ! It doesn't required any java-8 features.

Answer (score 3):

You need to override equals() and hashcode() methods in Student class for distinct() method of Stream API.

```
students.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: question talks about ArrayList.

Comment: students.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()); You need to override equals method.

Comment: Updated. You need to implement hashcode() and equals() in your student class.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a map whose key is `ssn`. Here `Collectors.toMap` will throw `IllegalStateException` if it encounters duplicates

```
students
      .stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getSsn, Function.identity()));
```

Or you could handle it in the merge function

```
students
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getSsn, Function.identity(), (student1, student2) -> {
                System.out.println(student1 + " and " + student2 + " had duplicate SSNs");
                return student1; //Just for demonstration I'm returning the first one.
            }));
```

The above will help you *identify* duplicates, but you haven't mentioned what to do after that.

**EDIT** (based on update to question):

*.. but i need to ensure lName values are unique too*

You could do the above twice - once for SSN and once for the last name.

Or you could override `equals` and `hashCode` as shown in the other answer.

Comment: wanted to do something like this, but i need to ensure lName values are unique too

Comment: @usr1234 So, both SSN and LastNames have to be unique?

Comment: Yes! i get the arraylist from a user request in an API and i need to validate that the lastName and ssn values in each element are unique,
and throw exception if they are not

Comment: @usr1234 I hope to never encounter a real life school that requires its students to have unique last names…

Comment: @Holger I hope so ;)