# How to create new array from existing without duplicate elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array of objects in java.
Something like this

```
array = [{month: 6, year: 2018, amount: 242}, {month: 6, year: 2018, amount: 345}, {month: 7, year: 2018, amount: 4567}, {month: 7, year: 2018, amount: 1234}, {month: 8, year: 2018, amount: 211}]
```

So I want to create a new array without duplicate month and year keys so this new array should look like this

```
newArray = [{month: 6, year: 2018}, {month: 7, year: 2018}, {month: 8, year: 2018}]
```

Here is function that I've implemented

```
private class IncomeArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<Income> incomeList;
        List<Income> listOfIncomes = new ArrayList<>();

        public IncomeArrayAdapter(List<Income> incomesList) {
            boolean found = false;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            this.incomeList = incomesList;
            for (int i = 0; i < incomeList.size(); i++) {
                if (!listOfIncomes.contains(incomesList.get(i).month + incomesList.get(i).year)) {
                    listOfIncomes.add(incomesList.get(i));
                }
            }
}
```

So I've tried with hashCode() and equals() functions but I'm new to java and I failed. So **I would like if some could help me and explain to me how to create this new array?**

EDIT:

```
   @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
        Income income = (Income) o;
        return month == income.month &&
                year == income.year;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), month, year);
    }
```

here is my `hashCode()` and `equals()` implementation. 
It should return only one list object if month and year are equal.

Comment: What is the problem with your current approach?

Comment: I have 5 objects in incomeList and listOfIncomes returns the same list

Comment: hint: For `contains` to work the way you want it to, you should be passing an `Income` to it. It looks like you're passing either a `String` or an `int` (depending on what the types of `month` and `year` are).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from a list of objects based on property in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670116/remove-duplicates-from-a-list-of-objects-based-on-property-in-java-8)

Comment: What i suggest you is too redefine your class `Income` extends new abstract class `AbstractIncome` where you put filed `month` and `years` and you put `amount` in the `Income` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `equals` implementation is correct, you should modify the if-statement in the following way to make use of it:

```
...
if (!listOfIncomes.contains(incomesList.get(i))) 
{
    listOfIncomes.add(incomesList.get(i));
} 
...
```

also another suspicious thing that I see is in the `equals` implementation, in particular the line:

```
if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
```

try removing it and try again.

Comment: Obviously, there is something wrong with my equals method because I'm getting back the list with all items in it

Comment: @RubyDigger19 You were not giving an `Income` object to the contains method. Did you change that?

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: Look at the code I posted. There is `incomesList.get(i)` as argument. You are doing some kind of append.

Comment: I have this `incomesList.get(i)` but I don't get it

Comment: You don't get what?

Comment: I don't understand. I've set the code you said but my array is still the same like original one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176669/discussion-between-niver-and-rubydigger19).

Answer (score 1):

You have to update if statement and pass income object in `contains` method. `contains` method internally calls `equals` methods.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < incomeList.size(); i++) { 
     if (!listOfIncomes.contains(incomesList.get(i)) {
                listOfIncomes.add(incomesList.get(i));
     }
 }
```

Comment: @RubyDigger19 you are passing `incomesList.get(i).month + incomesList.get(i).year` in `contains` method you have to pass `Income object -> incomesList.get(i)` .

Comment: I've create code like this but still getting the same array as original one

Comment: @RubyDigger19  I just  ran the code and removed this if statement `if (!super.equals(o)) return false;` and it worked for me.Can you remove this line  `if (!super.equals(o)) return false;` from the code and try.

Answer (score 0):

`Set<Income> uniqueSets = Sets.newHashSet(incomesList);` should do the trick.

Just make sure the `equals` and `hashCode` methods are setup the way you're expecting the logic to work.

Comment: I've edited the question with my `hashCode` and `equals`. Is it oke if you could check?

Comment: Your `equals` and `hashcode` only seem to care about the month and year.  I'd just make sure those values are the same.  I'd convert the `List` into a `Set`, which will make all the values unique.  If necessary, then convert it back or just return the `Set`

Comment: Did like you said but still getting the same array with duplicates

Comment: So then something is up with your `equals` and/or `hashCode`.  Step through the values in the debugger