# Filtering list under limitations

Tags: java, algorithm

### Description

The input is `List<Item>` sorted by score, `Item` looks like:

```
class Item {
    double score;
    String category; 
    String author;    
    String poi;   
}
```

Now I need to select **10** elements which have the highest scores from the array, under these limitations:

- They should have different `poi`
- They should have different `author`
- There are at most 3 items from the same `category`. And the length of any subsequence from the same `category` should not be longer than 2.

If there is no subsequence which satisfies above rules, just return the first 10 elements.

### What I have tried

Now, I directly iterate over the `List`, and use three `HashMap<String, Integer>` to store the appearences of each `cagetory/poi/author`. And I use `List<Item> selected` to store the result.

- If there is already a selected element that has this `poi`, then the new element will be discarded.
- If there is already a selected element that has this `author`, then the new element will be discarded.
- If there are already three selected elements that have this `category`, then the new element will be discarded.
- If there are already two elements in the tail of `selected` that have this `category`, then the new element will be discarded.

### Problem

It works when the input is large, but when the input is relatively small, it does not work. For example, when the input is

1. Item1(Category A, Author 1)
2. Item2(Category A, Author 2)
3. Item3(Category A, Author 3)
4. Item4(Category B, Author 2)
5. Item5(Category C, Author 5)
6. Item6(Category D, Author 6)
7. Item7(Category E, Author 7)
8. Item8(Category F, Author 8)
9. Item9(Category G, Author 9)
10. Item10(Category H, Author 10)
11. Item11(Category I, Author 11)

Then my solution will be

- `Item3` discarded, because it has the same `category` as `Item1` and `Item2`
- `Item4` discarded, because it has the same `author` as `Item2`
- the 9 other elements remain.

And this does not satisfy the `select top 10 elements`. The correct solution is discarding `Item2` and only 10 elements should remain.

### Question

I think my solution is just in the wrong direction. So I'm looking for other solutions to deal with this problem. Any solution produces the desired output is appreciated.

Comment: Your expectation is that `Item3` won't be aborted?

Comment: It seems that you want to remove duplicates based on property/ies see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670116/remove-duplicates-from-a-list-of-objects-based-on-property-in-java-8

Comment: Where is `poi` in you test list?

Comment: As an extension to your algorithm, you can keep for each item its original index and aborted item (along with their index) kept in a list. If you finished and have less than 10, put some of them back (ordered by index)

Comment: Is my answer below acceptable? Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: @Assafs Sorry. I did not describe the problem properly. So I have edited it. Would you please check the edit history and see if your answer is still doable?

Comment: @Assafs I am really appreciate your answer and trying to understand it. I'm not sure whether it is acceptable, because I know little about this kind of problem. I started a bouty to draw more attention on it.

Comment: You seem to only clarify the ways categories are formed - you can have up to n members in any category. My solution is a generalized algorithm to eliminate a set of items which correspond to mutual-exclusion rules and create a legal set. Following it will allow you to decide if you can afford to keep any item and still maintain a set of a certain size.

Comment: The question still lacks in terms of information about, what if any of the rules is not met Vs all of the rules are not met Vs what if at the second stage of rules the data is not sufficient. Also, the example by you would be much better with `poi` and score values provided.

Comment: I agree with nullpointer we need more detailed rules that will cover corner cases.  For example what do you do if you have 11 items and 2 of them have the same poi and another 2 has the same author?  are both solutions acceptable?

Comment: @nullpointer if there is no qualified result, just return the first 10 item

Comment: @竹杖芒鞋轻胜马 The question was more or so, what if after processing one rule, you're left with 9 elements. Would you return the complete list in the input at that point of time without further checking any other rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original algorithm you used will always tend to minimize the number of results, because in any mutual-exclusive choice between items the highest-score item wins. This way the algorithm operates like a sieve, eliminating many lower-score items.

In order to support choosing a set of at least size X (10 in this case) from an original  set of items length Y (11 in your example), you will need to collect a list of decision sets rather than eliminating items by score alone. A decision set(m,n) is a set of m items from which you must choose to keep n items and eliminate the rest. Since most of the rules in your system are single item of attribute x, most decision sets in your list will be set(m,1) - choose 1 of the m items, eliminate the rest.

The first pass on the full items set will populate the decision set list, and the second pass will go over that list and choose from each decision set the items to eliminate from the original set. Once a decision is made and the item/s are eliminated from the original set, the decision set is removed from the list (resolved). Once the list of decision sets has been cleared, your original set is legal.

The goal is to have the decision set list cleared in **at most Y-X eliminations**. Since an item can appear in multiple decision sets, you can also add for each item a "*survival score*". The survival score suggests the maximum number of item which will have to be eliminated if this item is kept. It is calculated per item by going over each decision set (m,n) and adding to each item contained **m-n** to its accumulated score.

Let's look at your example, and build its decision sets:

- Item1(Category A, Author 1)
- Item2(Category A, Author 2)
- Item3(Category A, Author 3)
- Item4(Category B, Author 2)
- Item5(Category C, Author 5)
- Item6(Category D, Author 6)
- Item7(Category E, Author 7)
- Item8(Category F, Author 8)
- Item9(Category G, Author 9)
- Item10(Category H, Author 10)
- Item11(Category I, Author 11)

The decision sets we compile are (note the survival score in parenthesis):

- Author decision set (2,1) = {item 2 (2), item 4 (1)}
- Category decision set (3,2) = {item 1 (1), item 2 (2), item 3 (1)}

Our goal is to resolve the decision set list in at most 1 elimination. You can see that all the items are with survival score **1** (meaning that keeping them will result in at most 1 other item eliminated) except for item 2 which has survival score of **2** (keeping it will eliminate at most 2 items). We cannot afford 2 items, and therefore we cannot afford to keep item 2 regardless of its score. eliminating it will resolve both decision sets and is the only option.

The more general algorithm can be more complex: in every iteration you eliminate the items with survival score you cannot afford, and if you're not near that limit use a combination of score and survival-score to decide which one must go.

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of items and you need to remove some of them to achieve your goal. You need to check if removing each candidate item can give you better solution! Try to remove each item that could improve your list and see if you have achieved your goal.

Here is steps to solve it with recursion:

1. If given list size is less than or equal to 10, then return
2. Build list of candidates for removal from your list (Item1, Item2, Item3 and Item4 in case of your example)  If candidate list is empty then you are done.
3. Remove each candidate one by one, call recursion and then put back removed item
4. In case of recursion returns true, you are done

Here is some pseudo code

```
bool recurse(list l)
  if (l.size() <= 10) {
    // cannot remove anything
    return false
  candidates = buildCandidateList(l)
  if (candidates.size() == 0)
    // check for top 10 items
    return true
  for each c in candidates {
    remove c from l
    if (recurse(l) == true) 
      // check for top 10 items
      return true
    add c back into l
  }
// just get first 10 items
return false
```

This solution is based on backtracking with recursion. Alternatively, I think it is also possible to build up bottom-up dynamic programming solution as well which would give better result in terms of Big-O complexity time.

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution is pretty good, not to mention efficient, however, you're not dealing with cases in which selecting the next top scorer is the best solution. In this case, this could only happen when selecting one item would result in a top 10 list of less than 10 items.

Decision sets (as suggested by @Assafs) would do the trick; however, a generic decision set algorithm is very ineffective for the general case of your problem. If you have to build full decision sets for millions of entries just to avoid a case where there are not enough input items seems like overkill to me.

Moreover, the description of the "top 10" result set does not reveal what's the correct result set in all cases. For instance, if you more items in the example you give, there's nothing to indicate that removing item 2 is the correct approach. It's not clear how we're supposed to measure which 10 are the "top 10".

What I suggest is adding a partial decision making process to your algorithm, that would on the one hand, not compromise the performance and on the other hand, will provide the means to tackle the short input problem.

To implement that, you need to keep a map from each of your already selected items to the items it caused to be disqualified. On top of that, you need to keep a map from each of the disqualified items to each of the items disqualifying it.
After you get the result set from your greedy algorithm, if you have less than 10 results, you go over the result set and replace items that disqualify a lot of items with the items their disqualifying.
The way you decide which items to check first is really up to you, since again, there's no description on how to determine what's "top 10". You can eliminate lower score items that disqualify more than 1 other items first, or look for the items that disqualifies the most, etc.
The important thing is that whatever algorithm you're choosing, your result set has a maximum of 10 items, and therefore, even if you come up with an over the top O(n^3) algorithm, it's still a constant 1000 operation algorithm which is in reality O(1).
Building the maps needed to implement this also require O(1) time during the running of your initial algorithm.