# Efficiently remove duplicate Strings from List by applying a custom comparison (not implementing equals)

Tags: java, collections, duplicates

I can only give a simple, (hopefully not too) abstract example of a much more complex use case. I'm working with a 3rd party library. I have a `List<SomeLibraryClass>` I want to remove duplicates from. `SomeLibraryClass` generates a `String` property. <s>Duplicates, in my case, are all instances of that class where the properties contain the same characters, e.g. "abc" == "bca" == "cab".</s> The class doesn't implement `equals`. There is a method to compare the instances, which conforms to the `Comparable` interface. It returns `-1`, `0` or `1`, and it's the only way to identify duplicates (can't be done by means of string manipulation and comparison).

So I know how to do the comparison, but not where to put it. I don't want to override `SomeLibraryClass#equals`. Therefore, anything like `new HashSet<>(myList)` won't help. I looked at `Collection#removeIf`, which I believe would at best be inefficient (please correct me if I'm wrong). I also tried the merge function of `Collectors#toMap`, but didn't get very far.

A source code example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SomeLibraryClass> myObjs = List.of(
                new SomeLibraryClass(), // generates "abc"
                new SomeLibraryClass(), // generates "bca"
                new SomeLibraryClass(), // generates "def"
                new SomeLibraryClass(), // generates "def"
                new SomeLibraryClass(), // generates "fed"
                new SomeLibraryClass()  // generates "ghi"
        );

        // remove duplicates by comparing Strings ignoring the order of their characters

        assert(myObjs.size() == 3); // abc, def, and ghi equivalent, respectively
    }
```

```
class SomeLibraryClass {
    private String someProperty;

    SomeLibraryClass() {
        // something
    }

    public String getSomeProperty() {
        return someProperty;
    }

    // no equals
}
```

I would prefer a solution using the Stream API, because it's usually considered most efficient.

Comment: Perhaps wrap `SomeLibraryClass`, where the wrapper constructor generates the `List<String> effectivelyEquals`, and the wrapper provides an equals (and hash) method.  The end of the stream can collect back to the original, unwrapped type.

Comment: @sashkins solution, but using a wrapper to avoid too many calls to `reorderString`.

Comment: Actually the wrapper is my favourite so far, although it will break the contract with hashCode.

Comment: Why do you think, `removeIf` would be inefficient? In fact [a `removeIf` based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672489/2711488) is the most efficient, if 1) you don’t need the original list anymore and 2) it’s a mutable, common implementation like `ArrayList`.

Comment: You pass a predicate to ```removeIf```, that, for identifying duplicates, would result in O(n^2) (comparing each element to each other). Wouldn't it?

Comment: No. If you follow the link in my previous comment, you see a solution which is O(n), as the predicate just looks into a (temporary) hash set which is better than the `TreeSet` based solution which is O(n log n).

Comment: I was able to achieve this with a TreeMap (as I said, it's a bit more complex than my original description), which has O(log n) for put and get. Additionally, as I wrote, I don't have correct equals and hashCode implementations. The comparison does the trick, and I'm happy with the performance now. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `TreeSet` using your own `Comparator`.

```
Set<SomeLibraryClass> distint = myObjs.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(
           () -> new TreeSet<SomeLibraryClass>(
                    // this is for duplicates, insert your Comparator here
                    Comparator.comparing(SomeLibraryClass::getSomeProperty)
                 )
          )
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with Collectors.toMap, as you have mentioned.

It should keep the first occurrence of your 'distinct' object.

```
public class SomeMainClass{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SomeLibraryClass> myObjs = List.of(
                new SomeLibraryClass("abc"), // generates "abc"
                new SomeLibraryClass("bca"), // generates "bca"
                new SomeLibraryClass("def"), // generates "def"
                new SomeLibraryClass("def"), // generates "def"
                new SomeLibraryClass("fed"), // generates "fed"
                new SomeLibraryClass("ghi")  // generates "ghi"
        );

        List<SomeLibraryClass> distinctObjs = new ArrayList<>(myObjs.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        obj -> reorderString(obj.getSomeProperty()),
                        Function.identity(),
                        (existing, replacement) -> existing)
                )
                .values());

        assert(distinctObjs.size() == 3);
    }


    private static String reorderString(String input) {
        char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chars);
        return new String(chars);
    }


    static class SomeLibraryClass {


        private final String someProperty;


        SomeLibraryClass(String val) {
            someProperty = val;
        }


        public String getSomeProperty() {
            return someProperty;
        }

        // No equals method
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that it's more complex than String comparison. That's why I got stuck here. I updated the question.

Comment: @siggi, do you mean your SomeLibraryClass implements Comparable and contains compareTo method? Or there is some static method that accepts 2 objects and returns -1, 0, 1?

Comment: The latter. It's a static method.

Answer (score 0):

If your class is comparable and the compareTo method returns 0 for object you consider equals, that is enough for a TreeSet to get you unique values.

```java
TreeSet<SomeClass> mySet2 = new TreeSet<>();
        boolean addAll = mySet2.addAll(myObjs);

assert(mySet2.size() == 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a wrapper class and streams. The wrapper would need correct `hashCode` in addition to `equals` in order to work.

```
public class Wrapper {

  private final SomeLibraryClass wrappedValue;
  private final char[] equalityParameter;

  private Wrapper(SomeLibraryClass wrappedValue, char[] equalityParameter) {
    this.wrappedValue = wrappedValue;
    this.equalityParameter = equalityParameter;
  }

  public static Wrapper wrap(SomeLibraryClass libraryClass) {
    char[] equalityParameter = libraryClass.getSomeProperty().toCharArray();
    //sort, so hashCode generates the same hash code for arrays with same elements regardless of order
    Arrays.sort(equalityParameter);
    return new Wrapper(libraryClass, equalityParameter);
  }

  public SomeLibraryClass unwrap() {
    return this.wrappedValue;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    //maybe cache the result?
    return Arrays.hashCode(equalityParameter);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Wrapper another) {
      return Arrays.equals(this.equalityParameter, another.equalityParameter);
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
List<SomeLibraryClass> distinctList = list.stream()
            .map(Wrapper::wrap)
            .distinct()
            .map(Wrapper::unwrap)
            .toList();
```